# Calculating geometric features using Zeo++?

Tags: geometry, pymatgen, materials-informatics

I am currently engaged in research involving metal-organic frameworks (MOFs) and I am seeking assistance with calculating specific geometric features using Zeo++. The features I am interested in are pore limiting diameter, large cavity diameter, gravimetric surface area, and volumetric surface area.

I understand that pymatgen offers an interface with Zeo++. Could you please guide me on how to utilize pymatgen for this purpose? Specifically, I am looking for instructions or examples of code to calculate these geometric features of MOFs using the pymatgen-zeo++ integration.

In case pymatgen is not feasible for this application, could you also provide the necessary commands or procedures for directly calculating these features in Zeo++?

Comment: Did you follow the examples in the [Zeo++](https://www.zeoplusplus.org/examples.html) page? They look straightforward.